# Django migartion fail, (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server at \'reading initial communication packet\')

Tags: mysql, django, database, django-migrations, namecheap

The company work had bought domain name under NameCheap (no Root access)

All I now need is setup the database and webpage will be working

My company system use:

Apache Version: 2.4.38

MySQL Version: 10.1.38-MariaDB-cll-lve

Architecture: x86_64

Operating System: Linux

Python: 3.7

Django: 2.1.7

but when I run `python manage.py migrate`

I had this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/letsilap/virtualenv/IOT/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/letsilap/virtualenv/IOT/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/letsilap/virtualenv/IOT/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 227, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/letsilap/virtualenv/IOT/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/letsilap/virtualenv/IOT/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 164, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server at \'reading initial communication packet\', system error: 2 "No such file or directory"')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/letsilap/virtualenv/IOT/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/letsilap/virtualenv/IOT/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/letsilap/virtualenv/IOT/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/letsilap/virtualenv/IOT/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 350, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/home/letsilap/virtualenv/IOT/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 379, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/letsilap/virtualenv/IOT/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 59, in _run_checks
    issues = run_checks(tags=[Tags.database])
  File "/home/letsilap/virtualenv/IOT/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 71, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/letsilap/virtualenv/IOT/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/database.py", line 10, in check_database_backends
    issues.extend(conn.validation.check(**kwargs))
  File "/home/letsilap/virtualenv/IOT/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 9, in check
    issues.extend(self._check_sql_mode(**kwargs))
  File "/home/letsilap/virtualenv/IOT/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 13, in _check_sql_mode
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/home/letsilap/virtualenv/IOT/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 255, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/home/letsilap/virtualenv/IOT/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 232, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/home/letsilap/virtualenv/IOT/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/letsilap/virtualenv/IOT/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/letsilap/virtualenv/IOT/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/letsilap/virtualenv/IOT/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/letsilap/virtualenv/IOT/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 227, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/letsilap/virtualenv/IOT/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/letsilap/virtualenv/IOT/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 164, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server at \'reading initial communication packet\', system error: 2 "No such file or directory"')
```

I did some searching on StackOverflow:

[Error during Django "Running migrations": django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32399831/error-during-django-running-migrations-django-db-utils-operationalerror-201)

[Trouble closing and reopening MySQL connection after catching/handling django.db.utils.OperationalError (2013, Lost connection to server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52228881/trouble-closing-and-reopening-mysql-connection-after-catching-handling-django-db?r=SearchResults&s=2|56.5221)

but it was not very helpfully

further digging on the subject lead to me believe that MYSQL database is denying the access to my Django app.

I could try this theory as I don't access to MYSQL setting at all

To summarzie; I need migrate on django app but I had error running the command.

Help, please, I really appracite if you could help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

This could cause by MYSQL DB having a time.

you correct this by going into the MySQL Workbench and set long DMSB.

Here the link on article responding to this error:
https://anothercoffee.net/fix-error-code-2013-lost-connection-mysql-server-query/

The mysql official document on this issue;
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-lost-connection.html

Hope this help